# What is this incorrectly tabulated integral?

Tags: calculus

Bierens de Haan (#17, Table 275) lists the incorrect result:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cosh[a \cos x]\cos[a\sin x]}{\cosh[2a\cos x]+\cos[a\sin x]}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ What is the correct value?

Comment: What leads you to conclude that it is incorrect? And why wouldn't this be an obvious piece of information to include?

Answer (score 2):

For $a=0$, the value of the integral is $\frac{\pi}4$, and the value is not independent of $a$.

Maple gives the following (graphical and numerical) dependence on $a$:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently a misprint in B de Haan; the 2 in the denominator should not be there. In this case, the integral can be written $$\frac{1}{2}Re\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\cosh(ae^{ix})}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$